# How to import Rails application folder in Aptana Studios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana

I am new to Aptana Studios. I am also new to Ruby and Rails. I have created a new application with Rails by typing command in command line as

```
rails new test
```

Now I want to import it in Aptana Studios. In Eclipse while importing an existing Java project, we look for a folder containing .project file and import it. But in Rails application folder I did not find any such folder. So can anyone help me to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a pre-existing project file, just import the root folder.

File -> New -> Rails Project

Select the location of your existing application and the dialog will change to state that there are existing files and the generator will not be run.

[image]

Comment: No it is not working. Whenever I create a new project in Rails it starts to create a new application. But I do not want that. I want the existing application that I have created by Rails to be imported.

Comment: Did you browse to the folder in the location textbox? You should see the message in my screenshot when you do so. The root folder of the application is the one that contains `gemfile` or `rakefile`, look for those.